# dynamic SQL help needed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL  statement that generates a series of update statement but it does not enclose the  value in the set clause and where clause in single quotation mark. does anyone know how to do fix this? here is my code.

```
  Declare @OldSSN VARCHAR(9)
  Declare @NewSSN VARCHAR(9)
  Declare @cmd   VARCHAR(MAX)
  Set @OldSSN='000000000'
  Set @NewSSN='000000001'

Select @cmd =  COALESCE(@cmd,'') +
'
   UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + Column_Name + ' = ' + @NewSSN + '  
   WHERE ' + Column_Name + ' = ' + @OldSSN +'
'

  From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 Where Column_Name like 'SSN%'       
 OR Column_Name LIKE 'ssn%'          
 OR Column_Name LIKE 'ssn%'          
 OR Column_Name LIKE '%_ssn%'            
 OR Column_Name LIKE '_ocsecno'          
 OR Column_Name LIKE 'Ssn%';

 Select @cmd
```

Output when executed

```
    UPDATE appl_view 
    SET    ssn = 000000001 
    WHERE  ssn = 000000000

  UPDATE ap_paid 
  SET    ssn = 000000001 
  WHERE  ssn = 000000000
```

I'm trying to figure out how to enclose the ssn values in singe quotation mark as show below

```
    UPDATE appl_view 
    SET    ssn = '000000001' 
    WHERE  ssn = '000000000' 

  UPDATE ap_paid 
  SET    ssn = '000000001' 
  WHERE  ssn = '000000000'
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but you can use two quotation marks ('') to create single quotation mark

Comment: Why are you storing SSNs in plain text? Do you know that this is potentially violating the law? Do yourself and your company a favor and encrypt this stuff immediately.

Comment: @SeanLange It's not illegal to store them plain-text, but it's not exactly the best idea, either.

Comment: Certainly don't want to be the next company on the evening news. The whole concept of storing SSNs in plain text in not one but multiple tables is just terrifying. Saying it isn't the best idea is far too soft in my opinion. Sure hope my data isn't in that system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use triple single quote marks to pass a quote mark into a string

Select @cmd =  COALESCE(@cmd,'') +
'
   UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + Column_Name + ' = ''' + @NewSSN + ''''
   WHERE ' + Column_Name + ' = ''' + @OldSSN + '''
'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are going to execute this dynamic sql at some point? If so, you could use the parameters feature of `sp_executesql` and not have to worry about quotations. (You do have to use `nvarchar`, however).

Here is a simple example.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Create a table to test against
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    TestTableID INT IDENTITY,
    Text1   VARCHAR(10)
);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Seed the table
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO TestTable        
VALUES  ( '000000000');
INSERT INTO TestTable        
VALUES  ( '000000003');
INSERT INTO TestTable        
VALUES  ( '000000004');

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Make and execute dynamic sql
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @cmd    NVARCHAR(100),
        @SqlParms NVARCHAR(100);    

SET @cmd = N'UPDATE TestTable SET Text1 = @NewSSN  WHERE Text1 = @OldSSN';
SET @SqlParms = N'@NewSSN varchar(9), @OldSSN varchar(9)';  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd, @SqlParms, @NewSSN = N'000000001', @OldSSN = N'000000000';

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Result should have updated the first row from '000000000' to '000000001'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM TestTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select @cmd =  COALESCE(@cmd,'') +
'
   UPDATE [' + TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + Column_Name + '] = ''' + @NewSSN + '''  
   WHERE [' + Column_Name + '] = ''' + @OldSSN + '''
'
```